# Unreal Engine 5 - Reduce Project size

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

There is an extensive guide for UE4 [here](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/TestingAndOptimization/PerformanceAndProfiling/ReducingPackageSize/) but nothing about UE5.

I also notice that by default a 10.6 Gb project on UE4 (unpackaged) will be only 7.1 Gb with UE5.

The goal is to be able to transfer easily the project between an EXT4 external drive (linux) and Windows OS and also share the project online. 10 Gb on github is a bit... too much...

Thanks in advance for a solution

NB: I tag it UE4 since UE5 is really recent and also most of the knowledge related to UE4 may apply to the UE5 solution

Comment: Maybe you can use something like git LFS https://git-lfs.github.com/

Comment: Looks nice but work only on Windows, I am looking for a Cross-OS solution

Comment: I think it works for major OS https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs

Comment: Consider using Perforce. Don't use an external drive, too slow